# Why are there dark patches on my oiled tigerwood handles?

Tags: wooden-furniture

I have sanded some tigerwood furniture handles. All the varnish seemed to be removed. I then oiled them with danish oil. However, some odd dark patches have appeared after oiling. The surface doesn’t feel tacky. What could be causing this and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Photo added- I’m not sure if the photo shows it very well, but you can see the dark semi-circles towards the bottom left hand side.

[image]

Comment: Photos help to explain situations like this, please add one to your question. If you have trouble with this, upload the photo to an image host like imgur and post a link to it in the question, someone can edit it in for you.

Comment: Thanks- added a photo now

Comment: I don't see it.   It looks beautiful.

Comment: I think it is a natural occurrence on bare wood without staining. Other than the uneven reflection of light, it looks good.

Comment: Thanks- that’s reassuring to know that you can’t see any dark patches.

Answer (score 0):

Probably marks left by the circular saw blade at the mill. Could've been well sanded but still not visible untill the oil revealed it.